# Linq join with last instance in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, join

I have a workflow table that takes all the steps of a process. Lets work with 2 of those statuses:

1. Saved (new item saved but not submitted yet)
2. Submitted (item submitted for review)

Now I want to create a BatchSumbit function that will submit all the unsubmitted items. For this I need to query for all the items which has a latest workflow status of "Saved". All the historical workflow entries for the item still exist and it can go from "Submitted" back to "Saved" a few times.

Here is the table structure:

[image]

Now i want a linq query that will give me what I require:

```
from wasteInformation in wasteDB.WasteInformations
join workFlowHistory in wasteDB.WorkFlowHistories on wasteInformation.WasteInformationId equals workFlowHistory.WasteInformationId
// Join with last instance in workflow table (where workflowHistory.DateAdded is greatest)
where workFlowHistory.WorkFlowStep == "Saved"
      && wasteInformation.WasteProgrammeId == captureModel.WasteProgrammeId
      && wasteInformation.WasteSourceId == captureModel.WasteSourceId
select new
{
    WasteInformationId = wasteInformation.WasteInformationId,
    FinancialQuarter = wasteInformation.FinancialQuarter,
    FinancialYear = wasteInformation.FinancialYear,
    WasteProgrammeId = wasteInformation.WasteProgrammeId,
    WasteMonth = wasteInformation.WasteMonth,
    WasteYear = wasteInformation.WasteYear,
    DateCaptured = wasteInformation.DateCaptured,
    WasteSourceId = wasteInformation.WasteSourceId,
    WasteDate = wasteInformation.WasteDate
}
```

The query as it is will give be all the saved entries for the item. I want it to give me the item if that item's last entry has a WorkFlowStep of "Saved"

---

Edit:
I've got something that looks like it works. Still need to test it some more:

```
var SavedWasteInformation = wasteDB.WasteInformations.Where(wi => wi.WorkFlowHistories.FirstOrDefault(wf => wf.DateAdded == wi.WorkFlowHistories.Max(wf_in => wf_in.DateAdded)).WorkFlowStep == "Saved"
                            && wi.WasteProgrammeId == captureModel.WasteProgrammeId
                            && wi.WasteSourceId == captureModel.WasteSourceId);
```

---

Edit:
My solution above and Vladimirs's below both seem to work, but after inspecting the execution plans Vladimirs's looks like the better option:

[image]

Comment: Why you need workFlowHistory at all if you are not selecting that? Only condition you have is workFlowHistory.WorkFlowStep == "Saved" which doesn't make too much sense to me? So you selecting wasteInformation by WasteProgrammeId and WasteSourceId that has any saved workFlowHistory?

Comment: As I understand you want wasteInformation by provided WasteProgrammeId and WasteSourceId with it's latest saved workFlowHistory is that correct?

Comment: Or you want to get wasteInformation that has workflowHistory with greatest date across all workflowHistories in db?

Comment: @Vladimirs - Yeah. Every time you save a WasteInformation it creates a workflow entry as well. Any WasteInformation can have multiple workflow entries. I want all the WasteInformation entries from the programme and source specified which has a lastes workflow entry with a WorkFlowStep of "Saved".

Comment: @Vladimirs - I've got something that looks like it works. Will add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that you have collection of `WorkFlowHistories` on your `WasteInformation` I believe that query will select `WasteInformations` with their latest `WorkFlowHistory` (if any):

```
from wasteInformation in wasteDB.WasteInformations
where wasteInformation.WasteProgrammeId == captureModel.WasteProgrammeId
      && wasteInformation.WasteSourceId == captureModel.WasteSourceId
select new
{
    WasteInformation = wasteInformation,
    LastSavedWorkFlowHistory = wasteInformation.WorkFlowHistories
        .Where(x => x.WorkFlowStep == "Saved")
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded)
        .FirstOrDefalt()
}
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Form your query, I think it might be best to leave out the `.Where(x => x.WorkFlowStep == "Saved")`, else it will get the last workflow entry with that status and not the last overall workflow entry. Then, afterwords I can check it the last workflow entry has status of "Saved".

Comment: @Carel sure, later in code you can easily check for if it saved or not.